# How to split last character of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have

```
var abcd = "matrix(1,0,0,1,114.0,256.4)"
```

as an String i want last digit (i.e 256.4 This may change to any other number like 256.45)
Can it be possible to get that number?

Comment: `abcd.match(/[\d.]+\)$/)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var abcd = "matrix(1,0,0,1,114.0,256.4)";
var result = abcd.split(",");
result = result[result.length - 1];
result = result.slice(0, - 1);
alert(result); // 256.4
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7pB4A/).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good task for regular expressions, try this:

```
abcd.match(/([\d.]+)\)$/)[1]
```